# Play Framework 2.2.1 - Eclipse Installation - Multiple Target Directories

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework-2.0

I am running STS 3.4.0 based on 3.8.2 of Eclipse.  Installed the Scala IDE from the update site:

http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html

Following the directions for creating myFirstApp from the Play documentation:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/IDE

Able to successfully run the "play eclipse", to generate the eclipse version of the project.  The question I have "as a Noob", is around the fact that there are 3 target directories (besides the .target).  Is there a reason that the "project" folder contains a target directory and another "project" folder within it that has a target directory?

[image: Project view in Eclipse]

Is there something missing in the configuration that causes these target directories within the project directory as opposed to the root target directory?  Or is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal. Unsightly, but normal, and it is found in every SBT-managed project, not just Play projects.

The root `target` contains the output of "your stuff" and is, in most cases, the directory where you'll find things like test reports etc.

The `target` immediately inside `project` seems to be where SBT puts its own working files - things like the `classpath`s that it has derived for the various scopes.

The `target` in the *nested* `project` beneath `project` is a bit of a mystery as it looks very similar to the "SBT working directory" that I just described. I have a suspicion that it holds the "first pass" of compilation, macro-expansion, etc, before a second pass comes through and populates one or more of the higher-level directories.

Suffice to say that *all of them* should be ignored by your version-control system, as specified in the [Play documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Anatomy) - i.e. for Git, your `.gitignore` would have:

```
project/project
project/target
target
```